# phpspec - get return value

Tags: php, phpspec

I want to get the *actual* return value of the object rather than a chainable object.

```
class Foo
{
   public $attribute = 'data';
}

class FooSpec extends ObjectBehavior
{
   public function it_is_a_test()
   {
       $attribute = $this->attribute; // I want to get 'data'
   }
}
```

Is there any way for this to happen?

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just in case anyone needs it

```
$attribute = $this->attribute->getWrappedObject();
```

It returns the actual return value of the function/attribute.